# Line break in author list for elsarticle document class

Tags: line-breaking, titles, elsarticle

I'm using the Elsavier document class `elsarticle` where the authors are added with individual `\author{Bob}` commands.

I have a long list of authors ([generated randomly](http://listofrandomnames.com/) for this example):

```
\author{Stormy Kilduff}
\author{Rosann Ursery}
\author{Sebrina Bucklew}
\author{Lashaun Valerius}
```

This generates two lines:

```
Stormy Kilduff, Rosann Ursery, Sebrina
Bucklew, Lashaun Valerius
```

Instead I would like to force a line break after a comma and produce something like this:

```
Stormy Kilduff, Rosann Ursery,
Sebrina Bucklew, Lashaun Valerius
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest thing is just to use non-breakable spaces `~`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\author{Stormy~Kilduff}
\author{Rosann~Ursery}
\author{Sebrina~Bucklew}
\author{Lashaun~Valerius}
\author{Sebrina~Bucklew}
\author{Lashaun~Valerius}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```